# Getting Select box value in Angular - without using ng-options?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to modify a form which is using a select box that is populate NOT using ng-options.

The form itself is bound to an angular controller. Is there still a way for me to know the selected value of the select box even though the select values were not build using ng-options?

I have the following

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-change="checkValue()"
```

but the checkValue function isn't even firing, apparently.

Any thoughts?

Comment: as a side note, I can fetch the selected value of other text input boxes on the form without a problem. It's only an issue for the select boxes.

Comment: I tried using ng-click instead of ng-change. still nothing is being fired.. kinda weird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `ng-options` to get the selected value. As long as your select element uses `ng-model` the value will be stored there.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectValue">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Now in your controller you would be able to access the value of the select using `$scope.mySelectValue`.

Comment: I would have thought so.. yet my watch is still not triggering.. $scope.$watch('form.address.country', function(newValue, oldValue) {. It's like there's another event that's interfering with it? Seems odd.

Comment: I've confirmed that I can get the value from another select box on the same page - and there is a jquery plugin used on the select box I'm having an issue with. Going to look into that further and will post again if it's related.

Comment: It was an issue related to another plugin/directive on the page.. I'll go ahead and mark Ryan's answer as correct - but it's true that you don't need no-options.

Answer (score 0):

You should always '.' your scope variables.

```
$scope.address =  {};
```

Then bind to

```
ng-model="address.country"
```

Comment: Totally agreed. In this case I was only trying to remove any weird nested value conflicts in the model - which was totally unrelated anyway. I'm reverting my model back to form.address.country, but thank you for pointing it out!